# Is UPDATE significantly more efficient than INSERT?

Tags: mysql, performance, insert

I've come across a PHP forum software which updates its threads views each hour.
So each time you view a thread, a row is inserted to a threadviews table with the thread id, then a script runs once an hour and updates the actual views count in the thread table.

My question is, what's the logic behind this? Why not just update the thread table (i.e. views = views + 1)?

Comment: Maybe it's to avoid locking the thread row for each read, and thus avoid having a contention point just for reads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

updates in general is way slower than inserts, you can think of update as delete and insert. updates might require locking to support ACID compliance of the DBMS, with inserts you dont have any locking.

Also, due to concurrency, you dont want to lock the row, and wait for the update to finish, think of this, what happen, while you are updating, you get a new visitor, you will lose that visitor. This is called the **lost update**. On the other hand, the cron job aggregates the visits and updates once an hour, since that row is read only, write lock wont affect your reads during the update.

Comment: Well, but from what I can see, it isn't THAT much slower. I mean, it might be a few times slower, but isn't it a minor performance loss since the run time of the query is so fast anyway?

Comment: it doesnt feel slower with small data, once your data grows big, and you have too many visitors, then you will feel the difference and you will run into concurrency issues. see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Insert is likely always faster. Look at it like this.

An **update** is first a search for all posts to update. In some tables that could take a really long time but with god indices it should be fast. It is then an update of data and on each update it needs to check table constraints and possibly update indexes.

An **insert** is the same without the search. It's also always one row (or it could be more but then it's actually more than one insert... ) that has to be checked against constraints and update indices.